# Confusing Widget of inline entity form

Tags: entities

Inline Entity Form ships with two widgets as `Inline entity form - Single value` and `Inline entity form - Multiple values` when I use `Inline entity form - Single value`, I only get add entity form and when I use `Inline entity form - Multiple values` I get option to add/edit both.

what I was expecting to see to have both add/edit with `Inline entity form - single values` with only difference of not allowing to have multivalued field in this case.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your inline entity form by writing a small module, (for this look at README and the ..api.php) you can set your default values by loading them from the entity. So your former entries are available.